# Converting The Product ID sent in Wocommerce REST API PUT request to the one that actually exists in the store

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a drug store that has both a physical and online shop. I’m using an inventory management software for my physical store which stores products in a database and assigns a random ID for each one based on its own logic. I need to sync my online store’s inventory with my physical inventory management software, however, the problem I’m facing is that the product IDs don’t match and I’d rather not change the IDs from WordPress and WooCommerce. I also don’t want to change the IDs from the inventory management software of my physical store. I had an idea to make the products’ SKU values on the website match the Product IDs from the inventory management software of my physical store. However, this method needs a way to alter how request handling through WooCommerce REST API functions. Meaning that the API needs to: a) When a GET request is sent, first read the product ID from the request and then match the said ID to the SKU of a product in the online store, and then return the data from that product with that specific SKU to the client. b) When a PUT request is received, it should update the product which has a matching SKU value with the ID sent through the request. However, this kind of request always returns a 404 or 400 error since the product ID sent in the request doesn’t actually match an ID but rather an SKU value. (Note that I cannot change the code for the request on the client-side to ask for SKU instead of ID). I’ve tried various hooks to alter requests and responses for incoming requests in WooCommerce but none of them actually worked since the request returns a 400 and 404 which means it declines before it can get captured. Hooks that I’ve used:
`rest_api_init`,
`woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_product_object`, `woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_product_object`. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out on this matter. (In case it wasn’t obvious, I’m using WooCommerce and WordPress as CMS on my website).

Below is an example of a code which I've tried and failed me:

```
<?php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_product_object', 'update_by_sku', 10, 3 );

function update_by_sku ( $product, $request, $creating ) {
  // Read the contents of the request and save them in variables
  $product_id = $request->get_param ( 'id' );
  $stock_quantity = $request->get_param ( 'stock_quantity' );
  $regular_price = $request->get_param ( 'regular_price' );
  // Find a product in the store with the same SKU as the product_id
  $product_by_sku = wc_get_product_id_by_sku ( $product_id );
  // If the product exists, update its stock quantity and regular price
  if ( $product_by_sku ) {
    // Get the product object by its ID
    $product_object = wc_get_product ( $product_by_sku );
    // Set the stock quantity and regular price
    $product_object->set_stock_quantity ( $stock_quantity );
    $product_object->set_regular_price ( $regular_price );
    // Save the changes
    $product_object->save();
    // Return a success message and status code
    return new WP_REST_Response ( array (
      'message' => __( 'Product updated.' ),
      'status' => 200
    ) );
  }
  // If the product does not exist, return an error message and status code
  return new WP_Error ( 'rest_product_invalid', __( 'Invalid product.' ), array ( 'status' => 400 ) );
}
```

Comment: I suppose any hook where the callback function has a signature that gets a `$product` passed already, won't do you any good here. You'll need to find an earlier point to hook into, where it tries to determine what the current product it is supposed to be working on/with, so that you can substitute your SKU for the internal product ID in that selection process somehow.

Comment: I suppose so, It's either an earlier point where it's possible to hook into, or there's another solution which I'm completely missing.
Could I create a custom API endpoint to capture the requests? so that they don't go straight to the /w3/products URL?
I think if I catch the requests on a custom endpoint I could handle them accordingly

Comment: Sure, you could add your own endpoints - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ Not sure that is really the best way to go though, because then you will probably end up replicating a lot of already existing functionality.

Comment: Although, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/ also says, _"The API exposes many fields on API responses, including things you might not need, or which might not fit into how your site works. While it’s tempting to modify or remove fields from REST API responses, this **will** cause problems with API clients that expect standard responses. This includes mobile clients, third party tools to help you manage your site, or wp-admin itself."_ - so it might indeed be better to set this up yourself, "in parallel" to the already existing endpoints.

Comment: You can try using the `woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object` filter hook. This filter allows you to modify the product object before it is prepared for the REST API response.

Comment: In `wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $product_id )`, try to replace the variable `$product_id` with `$request->get_param( 'sku' )`and maybe it will work.